# Why don't I get rewards from the Books of Ryu in other volumes?

Tags: .hack-gu

In .hack, if you didn't lock the Books of Ryu and get all the rewards from from them in a previous volume you would still get them in the next volume. However, in .hack//G.U, if you did the same, in the next volume you would get cash rewards rather than BGM or Wallpapers. Am I missing something when I start a new volume or do I have to unlock all the book before going onto the next volume?